# My.Computer.Network.Ping(<<servername>>) always returns true

Tags: .net, vb.net, ping

I'm trying to monitor if the other PC's in our network are up or are shutdown. Following myresearch I found `My.Computer.Network.Ping` is way to do this.

[Determine if remote Computer is available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9xkzk4s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he5sca5t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

So i created a testproject where i'm pinging 5 workstations.

```
WS0001 (non - existant)
WS0002 (non - existant)
WS3102 (existant)
WS3207 (existant)
WS3306 (existant)
```

However method `My.Computer.Network.Ping` always returns `true` no matter if the workstation exists or not.

**Question:**
Would anyone know why it falsely returns `true`?

I'm using the method as following. `m_Parameters("workstation")` is one of the workstation metionned above.

```
If My.Computer.Network.Ping(m_Parameters("workstation")) Then
   'The PC is available in the company network
Else
   ' The Pc is unavailable in the company network
End If
```

**Note :** Using `My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable` does not resolve the issue. I want information about the other workstations not my own.

**Note 2:** Screenshot from my commandprompt
Translation: "Ping Request could not find host ws0001. Please check the hostname and try again." WS3320 is the computer of a colleague of mine. WS0001 is our "Test Workstation" which is now not running (since more then 5 months) and is no longer known in our domain.

[image]

Thnx for the help sofar!

Comment: MS Recommends: The Ping method is not a fail-safe method for determining the availability of a remote computer: the ping port on the target computer may be turned off or the ping request may be blocked by a firewall or router.

Comment: You also might want to check if your DNS resolves correctly. In some cases, with a firewall, the PC's do "respond" because the firewall does it for them.

Comment: This can be an alternative that would work for you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1e9b5cx(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @user3036342 if the port is turned off then i would expect to recieve an exception or something. Yet i always get 'true'. The DNS-name is being resolved correctly, thats not the issue.

Comment: @svranken, are you sure it's not DNS? Some Internet service providers will take all invalid DNS lookups and "helpfully" point them to their own search page, at which point you'll be pinging their "helpful" server (instead of actually finding out that the machine you're looking for doesn't exist). What output do you get when you run `ping WS0001` at a command prompt?

Comment: @svranken you got wrong DNS in CMD ;) one null less (maybe the computers exist, because they are servers or others in your network, not workstations?)

Comment: Install wireshark and watch the command that is run when you execute your code.  That will tell you what is happening at the network level.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Sam Makin: Brilliant! That one worked!

Comment: Maybe their is neither a problem with your code, nor your DNS but have you debugged and checkt m_Parameters? with "Angry IP Scan" you could look for if their really is or not is WS0001 link-->[angryip.org](http://angyip.org) EDIT: So where was the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this method instead.

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx